# EPERM: operation not permitted, stat 'C:\IISagent\_work\1\s\src\apps\abp\.next\standalone\apps\abp\node_modules\@heroicons\react'

Tags: azure-devops, cloud

i am running a Azure DevOps pipeline with the self hosted agent of windows for building my react application but during the Archive/Copy task its getting failed i have tried give the admin permissions to the agent still the error is persisting

i have tried give the permissions the agent

Answer (score 0):

When you install self-hosted agents on Windows machines, you generally need to open the **Command Prompt** (or **PowerShell**) as **`Administrator`** to run the related command lines to install and configure the agents. This could give the agent services enough permissions to access the folders/files on the agent machines.

[image]